# undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, assets

Hi I was upgrading a Rails 2 app to Rails 3.
When I want to run something like: `rails c`, `rake -T`, etc. It throws this:

```
$ rails c
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:77:in `method_missing': undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0xb6569120> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/neoriddle/proyectos/interkids/config/application.rb:49
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:21
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

this was with `rails c` and next log is running `rake -T`:

```
$ rake -T --trace
rake aborted!
undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0xb658aa64>
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/neoriddle/proyectos/interkids/config/application.rb:49
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/neoriddle/proyectos/interkids/Rakefile:5
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Do you have some ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Asset pipeline wasn't included until rails 3.1. Upgrade your rails gem (and app) to rails 3.1+.

Comment: I will upgrade from 3.0 to 3.1, but now I need to finish my upgrade from 2.x to 3.0. Rails 3.0 is now required so for a while I need to make to work. So how can I fix (temporally) to make it work?

Comment: @NeoRiddle: Remove the line that references `config.assets` from the files in `config`.

Comment: Yes, for now you can remove every reference to config.assets. Make sure you mark the answer as accepted, since this was the answer to your error :)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, but it was resolved below.

Ruby -v: 3.0.2
Rails -v: 6.1.3

config/application.rb

```
require "sprockets/railtie”
```

terminal

```
$ mkdir -p app/assets/config && echo '{}' > app/assets/config/manifest.js
```

Answer (score 1):

My app was `api_only` so Rails skipped creating assets when generating a new resource.

I removed the references to `config.assets` from `development.rb` and `production.rb` and it worked.

So you can remove the references to `assets` if your App doesn't need it.